# How do I do a wipe and re-install on my Windows 7 HP Laptop while keeping Office Starter?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wipe, microsoft-office-starter

I have an HP Pavilion dv7 laptop that came with Windows 7 Home Premium x64 and Office Starter. It's been running slowly lately, so I want to wipe it. I have a Windows 7 HP disk (did not come with the laptop), and I know the laptop has a built-in recovery disk stored on the HDD.

I'm wondering if there is a way for me to wipe my computer (or speed it up some other way) while keeping Office Starter.

By wipe, I mean wipe and re-install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the recovery partition that shipped with your laptop to re-install Windows it will return to the laptop to *out of the box* condition. Meaning if it shipped with Office Starter it will have Office Starter after you reinstall from the recovery partition.

Comment: And your answer makes my question seem very simple.

Comment: Your welcome, once you get through it a few times it really is.

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/a/1161721/154326